# ng-list with line break as textarea delimter in AngularJS >1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-nglist

I'm using AngularJS 1.3 where the syntax for ng-list has changed slightly (for instance, it no longer supports regex)

I'm trying to specify a line break as the delimiter for ng-list in a textarea. However it doesn't work properly. I've tried to set ng-list to ASCII line break

```
&#10;
```

but then there is a problem. At once when the contents are edited (i.e. add one character to the textarea contents), it starts to break on every single character.

How do I properly specify a line break as the delimiter for ng-list in AngularJS 1.3?

Link to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/F37yA0LRHQXMh4caP3A0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We should use **`ng-trim="false"`**. See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBjenGqgo3nbnmQ7XxF1?p=preview)

```
 <textarea name="namesInput" 
 ng-list="&#10;"
 ng-model="names"
 ng-trim="false"
 required cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
```

See the doc [ngList](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList) *(small cite:)*

> If **ngTrim** is set to "false" then whitespace around both the separator and each list item is respected. This implies that the user of the directive is responsible for dealing with whitespace but also allows you to use whitespace as a delimiter, such as a tab or newline character.

Comment: How would I use a newline character as a delimiter, but also trim whitespace in each list item? In other words, I'd like to split each line in a `<textarea>` into an array element, but remove any whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.