# Display values in textarea separated with newline after post and reuse of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, textarea

I have a solution in MVC, ASP.NET with the use of angularjs, where it is possible to input values into a textarea and post them to a server. I can receive the values from the server and show them in the textarea in the view by using ng-model. But I am unsure of how to display them by newline and to then reuse them (re-post them right away).

1) First of all the user is able to input values in the textarea and split them by the Return button. This is done by `ng-list="/\n/"`:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" id="autoGenerateInputField" ng-model="fighterList" ng-list="/\n/" />
```

2) I then post these values through angularJS and saves them in my database.

3) I can now get these values from a JSON. I convert them into a list and puts them into the fighterList using angularJS:

```
$scope.refreshListTournamentTree = function (CategoryId) {
        var serviceUrl = "/api/Match" + (CategoryId ? "/" + CategoryId : "");
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serviceUrl
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.treeGenerated = data.length;
            $scope.totalMatches = data;
            var listOfFighters = [];
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $scope.finalMatch = [buildHierarchy(data)[0]];
                for (var i = 0; data.length > i; i++){
                    fighter1 = data[i].Fighter1;
                    fighter2 = data[i].Fighter2;
                    listOfFighters.push(fighter1);
                    listOfFighters.push(fighter2);
                }
            }
            else {
                $scope.finalMatch = [];
            }
            $scope.fighterList = listOfFighters;
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      });

    }
```

Now the list is shown in the textarea but the values are separated by "," and not with a new line. I have created a Fiddle that shows a simplyfied version of my question:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Jtf3M/256/
```

[image]

[image]

So to my question: How do I display the values from the fighterList in the textarea separated with newline and so that I can reuse the values?

Comment: maybe this question has an answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450445/ng-list-with-line-break-as-textarea-delimter-in-angularjs-1-3

Comment: I tryied this solution but with the `ng-list="&#10;"` it splits the values with "\": `["1\2\3"]` whereas I need: `["1","2","3"]` to post it to the server. Also the `ng-list="&#10;"` doesnt display the values separated with newline.

Comment: You could try to loop through the values in the array and add '\n' to each entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply add a `join`?
Please see the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtf3M/261/

Please look also at this alternative way using a filter and ng-init: http://jsfiddle.net/7516qere/

Comment: This displays it as I requested but I am not able to reuse the values, since the output now is `1 2 3` and not as an array: `["1","2","3"]`. I guess it should be possible to convert it into an array of strings?

Comment: you can convert back to array with `split` example: `$scope.fighterList.split('\n')`

Comment: Perfect. The combination of the join on the output and the split on the input did the trick. Thank you Michelem!